# radio button and button in two web forms in asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, forms

I am working on ASP.NET C# and I want to have two web forms, first web form have two radio buttons one for male another for female and regular button to submit the selection

And on another web form I want to see user selection of radio button.

First web form(test1)

```
<asp:RadioButton ID="RadioButton1" runat="server" GroupName="gender" OnCheckedChanged="RadioButton1_CheckedChanged" Text="male" />
<br />
<br />
<asp:RadioButton ID="RadioButton2" runat="server" GroupName="gender" Text="female" />
<br />
<br />
<asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" OnClick="Button1_Click" Text="Button" />
<br />
<br />
```

test1.cs

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

}
protected void RadioButton1_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

}
protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

}
```

Second web form (test2)

```
<asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Text="Label" Visible="False"></asp:Label>
```

test2.cs

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

}
```

So I want

```
if (RadioButton1.Checked == true)
{
    Label1.Text = "you are male";
}

if (RadioButton2.Checked == true)
{
    Label1.Text = "you are female";
}
```

To be in test2.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First,  you need a RadioButton list to save the Sex selecion.

```
<asp:RadioButtonList ID="RadioButtonList1" runat="server" 
    onselectedindexchanged="RadioButtonList1_SelectedIndexChanged">
    <asp:ListItem Text="Male" Value="M" Selected="True"></asp:ListItem>
        <asp:ListItem Text="Female" Value="F"></asp:ListItem>
</asp:RadioButtonList>
```

Then, in the "RadioButtonList1_SelectedIndexChanged" event, you have to save the selected value in a session variable

```
protected void RadioButtonList1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //Save the selected value as a session variable
        Session["SexValue"] = RadioButtonList1.SelectedValue.ToString();
    }
```

In the second web form, you recover the session variable value with

```
//Recovering session variable
        var sessionValue = Session["SexValue"];

        //Check if exist the session variable
        if (sessionValue != null)
        {
            //Parse the session variable to string
            string value = (string)sessionValue;

            //Do your stuff here
            //.................
            //.................

            //Clean the session variable
            Session.Clear();
        }
```

You can find more info about session variables here https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178581%28v=vs.140%29.aspx

Answer (score 0):

you need to first add a radio button control to your web form, this is usually achieved by adding it using the drag and drop features of Visual Studio. Once you add that button the .aspx page will automatically add a line like this:

```
        <asp:RadioButtonList ID="rbtLstRating" runat="server" 
            RepeatDirection="Horizontal" RepeatLayout="Table">
            <asp:ListItem Text="Excellent" Value="Excellent"></asp:ListItem>
            <asp:ListItem Text="Very Good" Value="Very Good"></asp:ListItem>
            <asp:ListItem Text="Good" Value="Good"></asp:ListItem>
            <asp:ListItem Text="Fair" Value="Fair"></asp:ListItem>
            <asp:ListItem Text="Bad" Value="Bad"></asp:ListItem>
        </asp:RadioButtonList>   
        <asp:Button ID="btnSubmit" runat="server" Text="Submit" OnClick="btnSubmit_Click" />
```

then in your code behind you'll have to attach a C# method to either that button changed event or the button click event. Hope this helps!

Comment: thank, the radiobuttons and buttons I already drag and drop them, but I want to send the result of the selection(male,female) to another web form because when I use labels null refernces problem appear

Comment: @lubna can you give an example of how you're trying to set the label text from the male/female selection?

Comment: just I want to display on another form "the user is male" or "the user is female" ,but my main problem is how to deal with two web forms

Comment: @lubna it would help if I could see the code you're trying to do this with. If you could edit your original post with the code that would be helpful. One way to achieve what you're trying to do is by having an asp:label and then setting the label.text in the submit button method.

Comment: I edit my question, hope now you are understanding what I mean, thannk you

Comment: I just want test2 label to show the result, some one said to me it works with session but I did not how to deal with session

Comment: You can save the sex selection temporaly (e.g in a db or session variable ) and after use it in the second web form.

Comment: @P0lyb1us can you please help me how to do that with session because I am new in asp.net

Comment: so are the two web forms completely different pages? If so, you need to find a way to store that value of whether they're a man or woman. This could be in a static class/variable, a querystring, or something like that. Also, the code you need to write that should achieve this should go into that check changed event. OR you don't even need the check changed event if you're going to use a button submit method, i.e. you could set a variable based on RadioButton1.Checked.

Answer (score 0):

place this code on web page 1 on submit click event

```
if (RadioButton1.Checked == true)
{
   Response.Redirect("test2.aspx?selection=male");
}

if (RadioButton2.Checked == true)
{
    Response.Redirect("test2.aspx?selection=female");`
}
```

and on second web page,

on page load check value of selection..

```
if(Request.Querystring("selection").Tostring() == "male")
 {
 //set label here
 }else
 {
 // set female selection
 }
```